# Service for getting data from Facebook API approval

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

not sure if this is strictly programming question (apologies in advance).
We have windows service which is responsible for downloading data from different API's on regular basis, it's just internal tool we are using on our server.

For purposes of oauth2 authentication we use our another tool, which can 
handle multiple Oauth logins through different API's, then we just ask this tool for access token and use it in our calls. This works perfectly with e.g. AdWords, BingAds, etc.

Now we have a task to download data from Facebook API. But the problem here is that according to FB we need to **apply application for approval** in order to get permission to "ads_read" source, which can allow us to download ad insights.

But the problem is that our tool is not an application it does not have any icon, screenshots or Privacy Policy URL. Is there any possibility to get these data without application to FB? Maybe is there another way to login and get the data from user without using oauth2, thus no need for using the oauth2 and scope permissions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're only using your app with admins/testers/developers of the same app, you don't need to go under Login Review. Only if you also want to authenticate "other" users as well.

Comment: Thank you Tobi for quick response, yes that's exactly the case, what type of authentication should I use in this case? I don't need to create fb app in developers section? Thank you

Comment: IMHO it depends on what kind of data you want to access (which is not 100% clear to me). If you need a user access token, you'll need to setup an own app, or use the Graph Explorer (which sucks, because then you'll need to replace the long-lived token in your application manually), or a page access token which can be eternal, and doesn't need to be replaced.

Comment: actually I need to access ads insights https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access as I mentioned in my question the data I need should be in ads_read scope

Comment: `ads_read` seems to be a user-based permission, although it's missing from the permission docs... Then, you'll need an own app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/overview#structure

Comment: Ok thanks, I think further reading and your answers, solved this issue, we could use our app only in dev mode to get the data :)